# Как передать данные из Middleware в контроллер в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Задача следующая: хочу передавать во все контроллеры данные о шапке сайта, которые получаю из БД. Как мне это сделать?

Пробовал вот так, но это, похоже, совсем не то:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $arr = ['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd'];

    $request->request->set('first', $arr);

    return $next($request);
}
```

И затем в контроллере пытаюсь обратиться так к ним:

```
public function getIndex(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->request->get('first'));
}
```

Кто нить знает, как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем передавать данные о шапке сайта в контроллеры? вероятно, стоит задача в конечном счете о передаче в View.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    view()->share(['a' => 'b','c' => 'd']); // переменные $a и $c будут в view

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно зарегистрировать синглтон в сервис-контейнере, синглтон будет хранить в своих свойствах данные, можно и получение данных из базы в нем реализовать

```
    $this->app->singleton('FooBar', function($app)
    {
      return new FooBar();
    });
```

Затем получить в конструкторе middleware свой объект и сохранить в нем данные

```
    public function __construct(FooBar $foobar)
    {
      $this->foobar = $foobar;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      $arr = ['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd'];
      $this->foobar->set('first', $arr);

      return $next($request);
    }
```

Теперь в объекте FooBar будут храниться данные, которые можно использовать в контроллерах

Comment: неужели нет никакой специальной переменной для этого случая?